# zip file download using php in ie8

Tags: php, zip

I was able to zip a folder and download the zip file using PHP code in "chrome" and "FF" browsers. But when I try that in IE8 it shows the downloaded zip file as a file of unknown type. I will have to open it with rar application specifically but I am looking to make this zip file download directly as .zip file in IE8 as it is happening in the other browsers. The following are the headers I used for it:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($archive_file_name));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
readfile("$archive_file_name");
unlink($archive_file_name);
```

Can someone please let me know where I need to correct the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
```

Make sure $archive_file_name is just a name not a whole path, also it needs to be url encoded and should probably have a ".zip" extension at the end.

```
header("Content-type: application/zip");
```

Why is the t in "type" lower cased?

Comment: Yes the $archive_file_name is just the zip file name and not the path. Also I changed the 't' to 'T' but it still doesnt work. please let me know if you need any more info about this

Comment: @user1489969 - try cutting down on the number of headers just have, content-type and content-disposition headers and make sure the file name is Url Encoded urlencode($archive_file_name).

Comment: I just tried that by having only the following lines:                                            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename=$archive_file_name");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
readfile("$archive_file_name");
unlink($archive_file_name); Still it didnt work in IE8. Please let me know if there is any other info you need

Comment: @user1489969 - using just those 2 headers in an ASP.NET (c#) generic http handler it worked in IE8, so your PHP configuration must be adding/removing something required by the good ol' Internet Exploder

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting some headers, some are needed just for IE, some for other browsers, IE is more picky.

Look at this link:

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I cut down several headers and just had: I just tried that by having only the following lines: header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); header("Content-Type: application/zip"); readfile("$archive_file_name"); unlink($archive_file_name); But still it didnt work in IE8. Please let me know if there is any other info you need

Comment: My bad. It was my fault it didnt happen. I missed the extension ".zip" with the file name and so this was happenning in IE8. now its working.

However I am trying out another thing. I am trying to upload multiple files at once in IE8. It works fine with the <input> tag as <input id="infile" type="file" name="infile[]" multiple /> in chrome and FF. But now with IE8. I think the <input> tag doesnt work with "multiple" in IE8. If anyone knows how to upload multiple files in IE8, please let me know.